# Createfile fails while reading mbr

Tags: winapi, mbr

Createfile fails while reading mbr on WinXP. Returns -1 i.e `INVALID_DEVICE_HANDLE`

```
HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ| GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ| FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,NULL );
```

Any idea why???

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add 'L' to the string constant "\\.\PhysicalDrive0".

```
HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(L"\\.\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

This is right only when you are using the unicode version of the API, i.e. CreateFileW().

Comment: If you are going to use `L"..."` then you should call `CreateFileW()` explicitially: `CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", ...)`, otherwise use the `TEXT()` macro instead: `CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"), ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

It's working for me.